# I select some results with 'GROUP BY' ,but the results can not be inserted into my table and report 1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql

I select some results with "GROUP BY" ,but the results can not be inserted into my table and report 1064 error

The “group by” results was total correct and the values was corresponding to the columns that i want to insert. But when I try the insert SQL on SQLyog it always show the 1064 error.

[image: This is the error MySQL shows]

sql query is:

```
INSERT INTO `admin_sales_list_count` (
  `entity_id`,
  `sku`,
  `comment_count`,
  `shaidan_count`,
  `sales_count`,
  `order_count`,
  `update_time`
) 
VALUES
SELECT 
  `product_id` AS `entity_id`,
  `sku` AS `sku`,
  SUM(`count_record`.`comment_count`) AS `comment_count`,
  SUM(`count_record`.`shaidan_count`) AS `shaidan_count`,
  SUM(`count_record`.`sales_count`) AS `sales_count`,
  SUM(
    `count_record`.`comment_count` + `count_record`.`sales_count`
  ) AS `order_count`,
  NOW() AS `update_time` 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `wsoi`.`product_id`,
    `wsoi`.`sku`,
    0 AS `comment_count`,
    0 AS `shaidan_count`,
    `wsoi`.`total_qty` AS `sales_count` 
  FROM
    `rder_item` AS `wsoi` 
  UNION
  ALL 
  SELECT 
    `acc`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`,
    `acc`.`sku`,
    `acc`.`comment_count`,
    `acc`.`shaidan_count`,
    0 AS `sales_count` 
  FROM
    `admin_comment_count` AS `acc`) AS `count_record` 
GROUP BY `count_record`.`product_id`
```

Comment: Solved: just remove the "Values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using insert into from a select statement, there is no need to specify the `VALUES` keyword..
Try the following

```
insert into `admin_sales_list_count`(...)   select ...
```

Comment: Tank you very much! Solved my problem.